# Reading formulas which are embedded objects from some OLE formula editor in a Docx file using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, docx4j

I am trying to read contents of a Docx file and save them in database using Apache POI api. I am able to read plain text and extract pictures but when it comes to reading equations embedded from some OLE formula editor , i wasnt able to find a method to read them . I tried many solutions but i am not able to get the equation read. Below is my code :

```
public class TestMyCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException,
            IOException {
        TestMyCode t = new TestMyCode();
        String fileSelected = "testTextBox.docx";
        File file = new File(fileSelected);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(t.extractDataDocx(fis));
    }

    public String extractDataDocx(FileInputStream fis) throws IOException,
            InvalidFormatException {

        String str = "";
        XWPFDocument wordDoc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));
        XWPFWordExtractor we = new XWPFWordExtractor(wordDoc);
        System.out.println(we.getMetadataTextExtractor());
        for (XWPFParagraph p : wordDoc.getParagraphs()) {
            printContentsOfTextBox(p);
        }

        return str;
    }

    private void printContentsOfTextBox(XWPFParagraph paragraph) {

        // Also extract any paragraphs embedded in text boxes:

        XmlObject[] textBoxObjects = paragraph
                .getCTP()
                .selectPath(
                        "declare namespace w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main' declare namespace wps='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape' .//*/wps:txbx/w:txbxContent/w:p");

        for (int i = 0; i < textBoxObjects.length; i++) {
            XWPFParagraph embeddedPara = null;
            try {
                XmlObject[] paraObjects = textBoxObjects[i]
                        .selectChildren(new QName(
                                "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main",
                                "p"));

                for (int j = 0; j < paraObjects.length; j++) {
                    embeddedPara = new XWPFParagraph(
                            CTP.Factory.parse(paraObjects[j].xmlText()),
                            paragraph.getBody());
                    // Here you have your paragraph;
                    System.out.println(embeddedPara.getText());
                }

            } catch (XmlException e) {
                // handle
            }
        }

    }
}
```